# remove duplicate elements from list in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, multidimensional-array

i'm new to programming and i'm trying to remove duplicates from list in python. However i'm unable to perform it using set(). List contains IP address and date following is my code and list

```
l = [['10.136.161.80', '2015-08-29'], ['10.136.161.80', '2015-08-29'], ['10.136.161.80', '2015-08-29'], ['10.136.161.80', '2015-08-29'], ['10.136.161.80', '2015-08-29'], ['10.136.161.80', '2015-08-29'],['10.136.161.235', '2016-03-12'], ['10.136.161.235', '2015-05-02'], ['10.136.161.93', '2016-03-12'], ['10.136.161.93', '2016-03-12'], ['10.136.161.93', '2015-04-25'], ['10.136.161.93', '2015-04-25'], ['10.136.161.93', '2016-03-12'], ['10.136.161.93', '2015-04-25'], ['10.136.161.93', '2015-04-25'], ['10.136.161.93', '2015-11-28'], ['10.136.161.93', '2015-11-28'], ['10.136.161.80', '2015-08-29'], ['10.136.161.112', '2015-04-25'], ['10.136.161.231', '2015-04-25']]

fl = set(l)
print fl
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/syeam02.TANT-A01/PycharmProjects/security/cleandata.py", line 18, in <module>
    fl = set(array)
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `list` type elements in a `set`, since `list` is mutable entity. For the same reason, you can't use `list` as key of a dictionary. You need to have an immutable type, like `tuple`.

So, you can convert inner elements to tuple before passing to set:

```
set(tuple(li) for li in l)
```

Check [this section to doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> Though tuples may seem similar to lists, they are often used in
>   different situations and for different purposes. Tuples are immutable,
>   and usually contain a heterogeneous sequence of elements that are
>   accessed via unpacking (see later in this section) or indexing (or
>   even by attribute in the case of namedtuples). Lists are mutable, and
>   their elements are usually homogeneous and are accessed by iterating
>   over the list.

Comment: Thanks Rohit this solved my problem.
now my data looks like this here we have different date and ip is same is it possible to keep only one date and IP
2015-08-29 10.136.161.80
2015-04-25 10.136.161.93
2015-04-25 10.136.161.231
2015-11-28 10.136.161.93
2016-04-02 10.136.161.231
2015-08-08 10.136.161.231
2015-11-28 10.136.161.235
2016-03-12 10.136.161.235
2015-04-25 10.136.161.112
2015-05-02 10.136.161.235
2016-03-12 10.136.161.93
2015-11-28 10.136.161.231
2016-03-12 10.136.161.231